# How to exhaustively list up the subscriptions made by AWS appsync graphql operation in React Native

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync

I am currently building a real-time messaging iOS application using React-Native and AWS-Appsync-GraphQL.

The basic architecture is when a user creates message on DynamoDB, the subscription triggers event function that renders the message to another users chat room.

The app has mutliple chat rooms and user shall reside in only one of them. Subscription is created when user enters the chat room and it become unsubscribed when the user leaves the room. And then new subscription is created then subscribed.

(Note that all subscriptions are specific to each chat room since I am using filtering argument for subscription.)

The most important feature to develop the app is how to manage the subscriptions. I need to keep subscribing/unsubscribing the subscriptions while prevents multiple subscriptions occurs. (I had observed that the app crashes when unsubscribed subscription stacked.)

Currently I had made a list and put the subscribed object into the list and  unsubscribes it when user leaves the chat room then empty the list. Then put another subscribed object into it. This process happens in sequence by leveraging ("async", "then") method in javascript.

The problem is I don't know why but sometimes the unsubscribed subscriptions occurs/stacks and makes error in the app, such as multiple message rendering.

So I want to exhaustively list up the socket connection that made by AWS appsync graphql subscription operation and then unsubscribe those all so that I could 100% guarantee there's no redundant subscrption. (I am unsubscribing and not making any more subscription when app goes to the background)

How could I list up the every socket connection generated in the app?

I couldn't find any documentation about this since all the google search results are tagerted into the In-app-purchase related subscrptions.

- The app link is as following. Hope this link could be an hint to solve the problem. https://apple.co/2rD0RP9

Comment: When you click ask a question on any SO site, there are a list of things (on the right) to be included to make sure the question is correct for that particular site. This site requires one to include specific code and errors. Other SO sites may be more appropriate for this question. Please review those sites using the hamburger menu for one where this can be answered or make it into a programming question with code example and error. HTH

Comment: @TommieC. Thanks for the guidance. Will there be any recommended SO sitesthat handles front-backend integrative architecture design for the mobile development?

Comment: A quick way to check the fit of a question for a particular SO site is to review the hamburger list for site overview and then click ask a question, read the guidance on the right and submit if your topic is a match. Also, search for similar topics to evaluate how such questions have been handled on that SO site before submitting. Software Engineering or one of the other computer related SO sites is most likely a better fit for this question.